# How to connect this array to this output

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I'm in way over my head here ... Teacher gave us two sets of code, this array with the function processTheText, and the body part (starts with textarea) that you're suppose to past a sentence or citation information into and split it. I don't understand how they relate to each other - when I click the button right now it does nothing. I'm not sure if I just don't understand the concept or if I've made some kind of error that's keeping it from working (I messed around with a bit, so that's totally possible). Any insight? P.S. Total beginner please be gentle. P.S.S. Javascript only. thank you!!!

```
<html>  
<body>  
<script type="text/javascript">
   function processTheText () 
   {
var medium = document.getElementById('textBox').value;

  var parts = medium.split (/[()]/);
  parts[2] = parts[2].substring(2);
  parts[3] = parts[2]
    .substring(parts[2].search(/[.]/))
    .substring(2);
  parts[2] = parts[2].substring(0, parts[2].search(/[.]/));

  for (i=0; i<parts.length; i=i +1) {
     document.getElementById("putYourOutputHere"+i).innerHTML= i +":" + parts [i];
  }
   }
</script>   

<textarea name="theText" id="textBox" value="Paste text here" cols="80" rows="25">     </textarea> <br> 
<input type="button" id = "myButton" value="Click To Run"   
onclick="processTheText()"> 

<div id= “putYourOutputHere”> </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Some of your quotes are fancy quotes. Change them all to `"` - also you have only one part so you get errors you can see in the console. Create a jsfiddle.net like this and debug using alert: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3At6Q/ - for example what are you supposed to split on? Your [()] does nothing for a normal sentence

Comment: Use `\.` instead of the one-character class `[.]` in regex.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to escape the full stop `[\.]`
2. you need to have some text that has words in [...] and (...)
3. you need to have more divs with IDs ending in 0-3 using correct double quotes
4. you need to fix your regexs

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3At6Q/)

```
<div id="putYourOutputHere0"> </div>
<div id="putYourOutputHere1"> </div>
<div id="putYourOutputHere2"> </div>
<div id="putYourOutputHere3"> </div>
```